# Shiny Package R error

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Everything was fine yesterday but now ben i runnApp, i got this error :

Error in .rs.getShinyFunction(params$name, params$where) : 
  attempt to apply non-function

I tried to uninstall and reinstall/reload package with no success. Even with the shiny example (runExample("02_text")), still the same error. I am very confused and lost.

Many thanks,

William

Comment: Add `sessionInfo()` output and [reproducible code/data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to your post. If we can't replicate your error, not much we can do.

Comment: Sorry about that. Anyway, I have found the error so this is the reason : if i load GrammR (package), i have this error when running shiny. I dont use this package anymore. Thanks for your help !